# How do I add negative radius to half circle?

Tags: html, css

I want to do this:

[image]

So far I got this:

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #red;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mariosmode/pen/abLrYXZ).

I can't get the top radius to go outwards the half circle like in the image.

How to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make a negative radius on a border.

There is the possibility to make an SVG path or [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient())... I made a new div as circle and radial gradient on pseudo-elements. It's not perfect, but it will possibly show you the direction to solution :)

```css
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.header-circ {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 250px 250px;
}
.header-circ::before, .header-circ::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
   z-index: -1;

}
.header-circ::before {
    left:-94px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left,  white 0%,white 75%,red 75%);
}
.header-circ::after {
    right:-94px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,  white 0%,white 75%,red 75%);

}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header-circ"></div>
```